# health check endpoint returns 404 when I call it in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, startup, health-check

I have this `RoutingHelper`:

```cs
public static class RoutingHelper
        {
            public static RequestDelegate OrbisDefaultRoute
                => async context =>
                {
                    var version = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CI_PIPELINE_ID") ?? ":(";
                    var result = new
                    {
                        version,
                        Environment.MachineName,
                        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
                        DateTime.Now
                    };
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
                };
    
            public static Action<IEndpointRouteBuilder> OrbisControllerDefaultRoute
                => builder => builder.MapControllerRoute("Default", "/");
        }
```

I added this helper in my `Startup.cs` as you can see :

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(RoutingHelper.OrbisControllerDefaultRoute)
            .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());


        app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new CustomAuthorizationFilter() }
        });
    }
```

But when I call the localhost:5052 I get 404 error code .Why?

Comment: Could you share your startup.cs file? Remember to hide the sensitive information. As I copied your code in my project and everything goes right. There may be some differences in the service.